# jQuery adding pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have made an really ugly code, but i was going to fix it when i was done with it.. But i didn't come that far >_<

i post my code here and some information under it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.cogwheel', function() { 
        var link = $(this).data('pageid');
        $(".pages").not(".page" + link).hide();
        $(".links").not("#link-" + link).show();
        $("#link-" + link).toggle();
        $(".page" + link).toggle();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.deletecross', function() {
        $(".deleteClass" + $(this).data('pageid')).remove();
        var total = parseFloat($(".hiddenCounter").val()) - 1; 
        $(".hiddenCounter").val(total);
        var this_val = $(".pagae" + $(this).data('pageid')).val();
        this_val.replace($(".pagae" + $(this).data('pageid')).val(), "");
        $(".pagae" + total).val(this_val);
    });
    $(document).on('keyup', '.pages', function() { 
        var pageID = $(this).data('pageid');
        var pages = $(".pagae").val();
        $(".pagae" + pageID).val($(this).val());
        $(".pagetest" + pageID).html($(this).val());
        $(".pagae").val(pages + $(this).val());
        $("#link-" + pageID).html($(this).val());
    });

    message = new Array();
    jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) { 
        //for (i=0;i<test;++i) { 
        if (message[test]) { $(".MenuLinks").append('<tr><td width="150"><a href="#" id="link-' + test + '">Sida ' + test + '</a></td><td align="right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></td></tr>');$("#articles_textarea").append('<h2>askda</h2><textarea id="editor-1"></textarea>'); }
        else { 
            message[test] = ''; 
            var TDRow1 = '<tr class="deleteClass' + test + '"><td width="150"><a href="#Sida' + test + '" id="link-' + test + '" data-toggle="tab" class="links">Sida ' + test + '</a><input type="text" name="pages[]" value="Sida ' + test + '" class="pages page' + test + '" data-pageid="' + test + '"></td>';
            var TDRow2 = '<td align="right" width="20"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog cogwheel" data-pageid="' + test + '" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Redigera"></span></td></tr>';
            var TDRowRemove = '<td align="right" width="10"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove deletecross" data-pageid="' + test + '"  style="cursor:pointer;color: #ff0000;" title="Radera"></span></td>';
            var TDFake = '<td></td>';
            if (test != 1) { 
                var TRRow = TDRow1 + TDRowRemove + TDRow2; 
            }
            else { 
                var TRRow = TDRow1 + TDFake + TDRow2; 
            }
            $(".MenuLinks").append(TRRow); $("#articles_textarea").append('<div id="Sida' + test + '" class="tab-pane"><input type="hidden" class="pagae' + test + '" name="pagae[]" value="Sida ' + test + '"> <h2 class="pagetest' + test + '">Sida ' + test + '</h2><textarea name="editor[]"  id="editor-' + test + '" class="editor" data-pageid="' + test + '"></textarea></div>'); 
            $("#editor-" + test).wysibb({lang: "en"});
            }
        //}
    }

    /* If no textareas available add a new one */ 
    if (message.length == 0) {  
        $(this).update_textarea(1);
        $("#Sida1").addClass("active");
    }
    });
```

This code you can add a page with, delete a page and write a new name for the page, and im using bootstrap so they all got there own "tab"

I was going to use this script to make an article system, and when you post it should insert pages into an own table like `pages`. And content to another.

But my problem here is, when im trying to remove a "link/page" it removes the page from the menu and everything.

But i dont have a freaking clue how to change the hidden input that has all the names of the pages in it.. So when i post the hidden input i got all pages i have on the page and those i removed..

I know this is some slabby code and i know you could make it better then me..

If you got any ideas or any thing that i can make smaller let me know..

Comment: Imo, you need to redo all your code and suggest you a deep reading into Software design patterns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

And also take a look to a great backbone + bootstrap CRUD tutorial:
http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/single-page-crud-application-with-backbone-js-and-twitter-bootstrap/

You can find some interesting ways to do things. Do software is not just starting writing code and see what happens...

Comment: I agree with @rusben ... Rewrite your code as early as possible, otherwise things will get worse!